# Coil Image loader not displaying image when using ListAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

My Coil load method does not convert my image Url to an image on my app. App does not give me a runtime not compile time error, It just doesn't show anything. Please help me as this has been so difficult for me as I am preparing for the Google associate android development examination.

```
class MarsFragment : Fragment() {
    //val marsPhotoModel: MarsPhotoModel by viewModels()
    lateinit var phot: List<MarsPhotoData>
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mars, container, false)
        val recycler = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
           lifecycleScope.launch { phot = MarsApi.retrofitCall.getPhotos()
               recycler.adapter = MarsPhotoAdapter(phot)
               Log.d("MarsFragment", "${phot[0]}")
           }
```

My adapter file

```
class MarsPhotoAdapter(var marsPhotoList: List<MarsPhotoData>) : ListAdapter<MarsPhotoData, MarsPhotoAdapter.MarsHolder>(DiffCallback) {

    class MarsHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val imageUrl: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imgUrl)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MarsHolder {
        return MarsPhotoAdapter.MarsHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_photos, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MarsHolder, position: Int) {
        val imgUrl = marsPhotoList[position].imgSrc
        val img = imgUrl.toUri().buildUpon().scheme("https").build()
        holder.imageUrl.load(img)

    }

    companion object DiffCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<MarsPhotoData>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: MarsPhotoData, newItem: MarsPhotoData): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: MarsPhotoData, newItem: MarsPhotoData): Boolean {
            return oldItem.imgSrc == oldItem.imgSrc
        }

    }
}
```

My retrofit file

```
private const val BASE_URl = "https://android-kotlin-fun-mars-server.appspot.com/"

private val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()
private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi)).baseUrl(
    BASE_URl).build()

interface RetrofitClass {
    @GET("photos")
    suspend fun getPhotos(): List<MarsPhotoData>
}
object MarsApi {
    val retrofitCall: RetrofitClass by lazy { retrofit.create(RetrofitClass::class.java) }
}
```

Comment: Try adding a listener to coil & check if any exception, error is thrown.

Comment: Thanks you DarShan. I dont really kow what you mean by adding a listener but I have added a placeholder and error image but still doesnt work.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/coil-kt/coil/issues/249#issuecomment-861681342

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Thank you DarShan. @AlexMamo So I noticed it is the ListAdapter that is not working correctly. I converted my listadapter to a recyclerView adapter and it works very fine. Then I changed my inflated layout file to a layout file with just a textView and noticed the listAdapter does not still show the text. So i guess I am doing something wrong with the ListAdapter. I hope you understand my situation?

Comment: If you try to log, are getting the right data?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes I get the right data. I noticed this when reading the documentation: While using a LiveData<List> is an easy way to provide data to the adapter, it isn't required - you can use submitList(List) when new lists are available. Does that mean I must always use LiveData? Maybe that is the problem. I will try it out after my lectures and revert. Thanks alot AlexMamo and DarShan

Comment: It's not mandatory to use a LiveData object. Since you are using Kotlin, you can use multiple solutions as explained in this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5).

Comment: @AlexMamo still have the same issue. I just used livedata and same issue. I am so disturbed.

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo and Darshan. So I have solved the issue. So my Diffcallback variable was not properly declared i guess. Thanks alot guys.